# Can I put a string, int, and double in a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector, void

In my program, I'm having an issue with one function trying to put three different types into an array. Is that possible, or do I have to work around this? I need them in one vector so I can recall that array in another function to delete it.

```cpp
void addStudent()
{
    string major;
    double gpa;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    int rand_ID = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
    cout << "Please enter major" << endl;
    cin >> major;
    cout << "Please enter GPA" << endl;
    cin >> gpa;
    cout << "------Add Student------" << endl;
    cout << "ID: " << rand_ID << endl;
    cout << "Major: " << major << endl;
    cout << "GPA: " << gpa << endl;
    
    ofstream students;
    students.open("students.txt", ios_base::app);

    students << rand_ID << " " << major << " " << gpa << endl; // I want to turn this into an array that I can send to the file students 
}
```

Comment: What does the different types or values represent? Perhaps it's time to continue reading your book or tutorial and start working with *classes* (if you want to group the values together)? But please tell us the actual underlying problem you need to solve. ***Why*** do you need to store these different type in the array? And why do you think that would solve your problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to create a class to hold all three pieces of data.

Comment: Take a look at std::variant and std::tuple to see if one  addresses your needs.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to put different students in a vector; and those students will be represented by a `struct` containing an `int` ID, `string` major and `double` GPA.

```
struct Student {
  int id;
  std::string major;
  double gpa;
};

std::vector<Student> students;
```